# firebase https link to change realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Does anyone know if Firebase has the functionality for me to email a user with a yes/no question which in turn offers two links, if one of those links are clicked it then changes a specific value on a node in the database?

In my mind I would use a firebase function to email the user when a certain trigger occurs, and the body of that email would be a template where upon the two links can be added as needed.

I have been searching online but either am using the wrong key words or the functionality does not exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Cloud Functions for Firebase. Essentially you would want to have two functions: one that sends the email and one that handles the links in the email.

If I were building it, I'd probably generate a secret token when I sent the email and store it along-side the question's data. In the email template, I'd then have the yes/no buttons point to my function URL like:

```
https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/respond?answer=yes&token={the_generated_token}
```

I'd then parse the answer and token from the query string in my `respond` function, verify that the secret token matches, and if so record the response. Once the response was recorded, I'd invalidate the secret token somehow so it could only be used once.